# Why KingSpec ne-120GB is much slower than it sould be

Tags: pci-express, nvme

I've added the KingSpec NVME 120GB card to my computer, using PCI-E single-lane adapter.

According to the [statement of the seller](https://www.guru3d.com/news-story/kingspec-releases-nvme-1-3-compatible-ne-series-m-2-ssd.html), this card's speed should be:

- sustained read speed of 1500MB/s
- sustained write speed of 500MB/s

But the benchmark reports speed of:

- sustained read speed of 410MB/s
- sustained write speed of 350MB/s

Has been tried with 2 different adapters:

- [NFHK N-M2X1 VER 1.0](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Nvme-Pcie-M-2-Ngff-Ssd-To-Pcie-X1-Adapter-Card-Pcie-X1-To-M-2-Card-With-Brac-JE-/352931275744)
- [PCENVME-N01 VER006S](https://www.ebay.com/itm/PCIE-to-M2-Adapter-PCI-Express-3-0-x1-to-NVME-SSD-Adapter-Support-2230-2242-2-SN/352826793968)

**Why?

Is the problem with the NVME-card or with the adapters?

Maybe driver or settings?**

P.S. The benchmark of the SSD (TS256GSSD230S) is actually what the manufacturer states (550MB/s read, 500MB/s write), so probably the problem is not with the benchmark program.

[image: KingSpec N-120 benchmark]

Comment: possibly because it is on a pciex1 bus.

Comment: PCIe x1 Gen2 is at max speed just under SATA3. Your benchmarks are what I'd expect from using such an adapter.

Comment: PCIe x1 Gen2 should be 500 MB/s for both read&write.
This is working even slower, at 410-R/350-W.

Comment: Table of PCI-E speeds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions

Comment: @Dani-Br That's the theoretical max speed. The actual speed is much slower because of a lot of factors. SATA3 is 600MB/s and reaching that is impossible as well. //// What is your motherboard? We can give you a possible solution if you give us your specs.

Comment: Statement straight form the description of the first adapter `It is mainly used for batch test firmware upgrade of solid-state hard disk or emergency use when some motherboards have insufficient PCIe X4 interface.The SSD with this adapter card can't run at full speed!` the second adapter doesn't even seem to have any vendor information.

Comment: From the ebay description it's not passive as it's converting protocols to make the x4 card work on a x1 slot.

Comment: my motherboard looks like this one: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HLB12c9maIrrK1Rjy1zeq6xalFXa3/E5-3-5C-Motherboard-MATX-Motherboard-SATA-3-0-and-USB-3-0-Ports-LGA2011-I7.jpg

Comment: the PCIEx16 is occupied by GPU.

Comment: @Seth: I might be wrong, but PCIe shouldn't need active conversion for that, as devices negotiate supported modes all the way down to x1 -- AFAIK, simply having the remaining 3 lanes physically unconnected would do the job.

Comment: @user1686 I'm just repeating what's on the product page: `This transfer card converts the M.2 NGFF solid-state hard disk of PCIe X4 or PCIe X2 interface protocol into the PCIE X1 interface on the desktop motherboard.` I don't know PCI-E to comment on your statement. There might be a variety of factors that might or might not make negotiation work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the Kingdian SSD performs slower than expected is because you are using a PCIe adapter at X1 lanes. Your motherboard, the E5 3.5C only has a single PCIe x16 slot (which you have populated) and two PCIe Gen2 x1 slots. The maximum **theoretical** bandwidth of PCIe Gen2 is 500MB/S per lane. Because of overhead and multiple other factors, the actual speed will vary per system. Thus, your speeds are the expected speed for an NVMe drive on the PCIe Gen2 Slot.

Sadly, you have no solution for a quicker storage speed given your motherboard. Your motherboard only supports first gen USB3, which is on average much slower than SATA3. You also have a single SATA3 slot because of the chipset, thus are limited to a single high-speed drive.

The only way to get a better speed is to change your motherboard. If you want to keep your existing CPU and RAM, then the simplest solution is getting a new X79 motherboard with a second PCIe X4 or X16 slot.